# Como comparar la ultima posición de un String

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema, no sabría como comparar la última posición de un `String` con un carácter alfabético.

```
// El DNI me lo pasarían por pantalla
for(int i=0; i<DNI.lenght; i++){
  if ((DNI.lenght-1) != //letra (de todo el abecedario))
{
...
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar la ultima letra primero debes de obtenerla. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Con el método **charAt**, donde la posicion sera el `length` -1 (algo parecido a como lo tienes puesto):

```
char ultimaLetra = DNI.charAt(DNI.length()-1);
System.out.println(ultimaLetra);
```

O puedes hacerlo tambien con **substring**, que devolvera una cadena y no un caracter como hace **charAt**:

```
String ultimaLetra = DNI.substring(DNI.length() - 1);
System.out.println(ultimaLetra);
```

Ya con esto obtienes la ultima letra, solo te quedaría compararla con lo que desees.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el ultimo carácter puedes usar `chartAt()` y luego usar `Character` y sus métodos para saber si es numero o letra

```
 String DNI = "cadena0";
    char mchar = DNI.charAt(DNI.length() - 1);
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(mchar)) {
        System.out.println("es letra");
    } else {
        System.out.println("es numero");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Para tratar una cadena de caracteres, se la puede tratar de a uno en uno utilizando el metodo de String cadena.charAt(indice).
>   Como lo que queres es el último caracter de la cadena necesitas saber cuantos caracteres tiene la cadena, para lo que se usa el metodo de String, cadena.length().

```
//Acá usamos DNI.length()-1 porque el indice de charAt comienza desde 0.
char ultimoCaracter = DNI.charAt(DNI.length()-1);
```

> Una vez que se tiene el último caracter guardado en la variable ultimoCaracter, te  fijas si es una letra del alfabeto, el tipo de dato char, tiene la posibilidad de recorrerlo cual si fueran enteros, ya que tienen siguiente y anterior por lo que 'a' < 'b' y 'a'+1 ='b'.
>   Por ello sugiero preguntar si tu caracter esta entre ['a' y 'z'] o entre ['A' y 'Z'] o si es'ñ' o 'Ñ'

```
boolean esAlfabetico;
esAlfabetico=(ultimoCaracter >= 'A'&&ultimoCaracter<='Z')
||(ultimoCaracter >= 'a'&&ultimoCaracter<='z'||ultimoCaracter=='ñ'||ultimoCaracter=='Ñ');
```

> Luego la variable booleana esAlfabetico se vuelve verdadera si el caracter esta entre  ['a' y 'z'] o entre ['A' y 'Z'] o si es'ñ' o 'Ñ' o falsa de lo contrario.

Comment: Deberías explicar cómo el código que has escrito soluciona el problema planteado.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas simplemente obtener el último carácter de un `DNI`, puedes usar el método [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) :

```
  String DNI = "99323664G";
  System.out.println("último caracter: " + DNI.substring(DNI.length() - 1));
```

salida:

```
último caracter: G
```

Pero si lo que deseas es obtener el último carácter No numérico puedes usar un `REGEX` para eliminar los valores numéricos y obtener posteriormente el último carácter:

```
 String DNI = "99323664G12A38";

 //Elimina valores numericos.
 DNI = DNI.replaceAll("[\\d.]", "");

 //Obtiene último caracter
 System.out.println("último caracter: " + DNI.substring(DNI.length() - 1));
```

Salida:

```
último caracter: A
```